# Django near "from": syntax error, trying annotate by month

Tags: django

I'm trying annotate date by month, and done this:

```
class Month(Func):                                                     
     function = 'EXTRACT'                                
     template = '%(function)s(MONTH from %(expressions)s)'
     output_field = models.IntegerField()
```

And then

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(month=Month('visited_at'))
    .values('month')
    .annotate(total=Sum('coins_counted'))
    .order_by('month')
```

And getting error:

```
OperationalError: near "from": syntax error
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What database are you using? I had similar issues with SQLITE while the very same code was working well with Postgres. SQLITE has very limited aggregate functions: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this, but an apparent syntax error is that "MONTH" needs to be written as a string in SQL, so try change the template line to this:

```
 template = "%(function)s('MONTH' from %(expressions)s)"
```

(This is how the SQL created by django built in `month` lookup looks like anyway.)